# Remote Kafka JMX - Connection refused

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I am running kafka10 on a remote server and the JMX is enabled on port 9999.

> **JMX URL :-** **service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://kafka_host:9999/jmxrmi**

When i try to connect to the JMX from my local network, it works fine and getting response within few secs.

But when i try to connect from my test servers, we get connection refused.
The ACL is opened from this host to the kafka host on port 9999.

Application code,

```
    TopicJMXMetrics jmxMetrics = new TopicJMXMetrics();
                   JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(jmxUrl);
   JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, null);
                   MBeanServerConnection connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

Is there any other setting required from Kafka or on the Application Side? Or, any other port to be opened

Thanks